# Set values in xarray DataArray to NaN if all values across a dimension are zero

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray like this:

```
import xarray as xr

da1 = xr.DataArray([[0, 1, 5, 5], [1, 2, 2, 0], [9, 3, 2, 0]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da2 = xr.DataArray([[0, 2, 9, 3], [0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 2, 6, 0]], dims=['x', 'y'])
da3 = xr.DataArray([[0, 7, 2, 0], [7, 2, 6, 0], [0, 6, 1, 0]], dims=['x', 'y'])

combined = xr.concat([da1, da2, da3], 'band')
```

It looks like this:

```
array([[[0, 1, 5, 5],
        [1, 2, 2, 0],
        [9, 3, 2, 0]],

       [[0, 2, 9, 3],
        [0, 0, 7, 0],
        [0, 2, 6, 0]],

       [[0, 7, 2, 0],
        [7, 2, 6, 0],
        [0, 6, 1, 0]]])
```

with three dimensions: `band`, `x` and `y`.

I want to set the values in this array to NaN in the situations where all the values across the `band` dimension are zero. For example, the values at `combined.isel(x=0, y=0)` should be set to NaN, as all those values are zero, but the values at `combined.isel(x=1, y=1)` should not be, as only one of the values is zero.

How can I do this?

I've tried using:

```
combined.where(combined != 0)
```

but this sets all values that are zero to NaN, which doesn't do what I want.

I then tried something like:

```
combined.where((combined.isel(band=0) != 0) & (combined.isel(band=1) != 0) & (combined.isel(band=2) != 0))
```

but the 'and' bit doesn't seem to work properly and it gives a strange (and incorrect) result.

**Update:** As an extension, I would like to be able to do the same thing but for very small values, rather than zeros. For example, setting all values across the `band` dimension to NaN if all values across that dimension are < 0.01. Is there an easy way to do this?

Any advice very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
combined.where(combined.any(dim = 'band'))
```

Comment: Thank you.

Having tried this, I've actually realised I need to do something slightly more complicated - I've updated the question, would you be able to take a quick look?

Comment: @robintw It's certainly not optimal but I think you can do it with clip : `(combined.clip(min = 0, max = cutoff) != combined).any(dim = "band")`

Comment: @robintw Glad it helped. By the way, your free GIS data list is an old favourite of mine. Very handy!